# Rounding duration (hh:mm:ss) to the nearest 0.5

Tags: javascript

I am looking to round a duration that is in the format of hh:mm:ss into the closest 0.5.

for example:
Duration: 2:28:55
Desired output: 2.5 hours

I can do this pretty easily in Excel using MROUND:
=MROUND((L3*24),0.5) where L3 is 2:28:55.

I have played around with some Math.round, however, it seems to round down.  Please excuse my js below, efficiency is not my strong suit with Javascript yet.  The below rounds to 2.

```
var hms = '2:28:55';   // your input string
var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons
console.log('var a = ' + a)
// minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
var hours = seconds / 60 / 60
console.log('seconds = ' + seconds);
console.log('Hours = ' + hours);
var final = Math.round(hours,0.5);
console.log(final);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) doesn't take a second parameter, it always rounds to the nearest whole number, but what you could do it just

```
var final = Math.round(hours*2)/2;
```

```js
var hms = '2:28:55';   // your input string
var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons
console.log('var a = ' + a)
// minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
var hours = seconds / 60 / 60
console.log('seconds = ' + seconds);
console.log('Hours = ' + hours);
var final = Math.round(hours*2)/2;
console.log(final);
```